# How to slide child element the length of parent on hover?

Tags: html, css, slider

I am creating a slider in CSS and I'm trying to make the `child` element slide the length of the `parent` container, no matter what the width of the `parent` container is. I currently have the width of the parent container set to `22%`. This is my first attempt at trying to make the `child` slide the length of the `parent`:

```css
div.parent {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 22%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 30%;
}
div.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #888;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: .5s;
}
div.parent:hover div.child {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, that's not the solution. I found this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nprs7/) that had a pretty good solution. However, when I move mouse within the `parent` container, the `child` moves back and forth (see example below). I would like the `child` element to stay still regardless if the mouse is moving within the slider or not (just like how it behaves in the snippet above).

```css
div.parent {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 22%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 30%;
}
div.child-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all .5s;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #333;
}
div.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #888;
  transition: inherit;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
div.child-wrapper:hover {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    background: orange;
}

div.child-wrapper:hover div.child {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child-wrapper">
    <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there another way that I can make the `child` element slide the length of the `parent` element, regardless of the width of the `parent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an absolutely positioned child you can use the left (and right, top, etc) properties to position the child. See below.

Remember transform% is the percentage of the element's width, not the parent's. If you see the child cube, translateX just moves it the width of the child in the X direction

```css
div.parent {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width:52%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-width: 30%;
}
div.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  left:0;
  background-color: #888;
  transition: inherit;
  z-index: 0;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: .5s;
}
div.parent:hover div.child {
    left:100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even simpler version here using margin-left instead:

```css
.parent {
  width: 52%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: #888;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  margin-left: 100%;
  translate: -100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```